# Overriding IReadOnlyList with a List in a derived interface

Tags: c#, interface, architecture, polymorphism

Here's a piece of code that I'm struggling to make work:

```
public interface IReadOnlyGameState
{
    IReadOnlyList<PlayerModel> Players { get; }
}

public interface IGameState : IReadOnlyGameState
{
    new List<PlayerModel> Players { get; set; }
}

public class GameState : IGameState
{
    public List<PlayerModel> Players { get; set; }
}
```

As you can imagine that doesn't work because there's a type mismatch between IReadOnlyList in the ReadOnly interface and the List in the regular one. How can I create a ReadOnly interface for properties that are collections?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your class must implement both properties.

You can Implement interface explicitly so it wont be directly accessible from the class itself.

```
public class GameState : IGameState
{
    public List<PlayerModel> Players { get; set; }

    IReadOnlyList<PlayerModel> IReadOnlyGameState.Players => Players.AsReadOnly();
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I was wondering if there was any way around that to tick all the boxes with a single implementation. Looks like there's no other way.

Comment: if you dont really need the readonly interface just dont use it. this is the issue many programmers have. they want to imitate from .Net types like List and IReadOnlyList. its necessary for .Net types because it meant to be general purpose and its a library. but your type is most likely just used in your own game.

Comment: It's actually pretty important for my use-case. My game client is going to use the ReadOnly interface, while the server will use the regular one. Guess I'm sticking with your solution. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @user1255410 glad it helped. notice that clients can easily cast `Players` from readonly to regular list and modify the collection! if you want to prevent that return this value instead. `IReadOnlyGameState.Players => Players.AsReadOnly();`

Comment: Ive fixed my answer.